# Injecting ViewModel into the Fragment with Dagger 2, with parameters

Tags: android, viewmodel, dagger

I'm trying to use a single factory for creating ViewModels with constructor parameters.
I followed the recommendation in one of the open dagger issues by @matejdro
https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1273

But the injection  doesn't work.

I"m getting an error:"error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] kotlin.Lazy cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method."

Any idea how to resolve the issue?
I uploaded my created project to github: https://github.com/davida5/daggerViewModelBestPractice

Comment: You should also probably be using Provider instead of Lazy (see comments in the linked github thread).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's pretty simple, you should be using `dagger.Lazy` (include an import for it) instead of the `kotlin.Lazy`

Once that is fixed you will run into another issue though; AFAIK you can't use a qualified dependency without a corresponding qualified provider. You have a qualified `UserManager` instance being injected into `AccountsViewModel`. Either add a qualified provider method or remove the qualification from the `AccountsViewModel`.

Comment: This is amazing. It removes all the complexity and no need for factories. Are there any drawbacks to this though, for us to keep in mind in the future?

Comment: Good question. I have yet to use this approach myself on a sizable project. In small projects it is pretty manageable, but I don't know how well it'll translate to the one with a large number of view models.